# Angular 6 Mat AutoComplete - Not Filtering as required

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular6

I am using Angular Material for my project and using mat auto complete to show the values.

I want to filter the values in autocomplete through `pipe` functionality available in angular.

```
<form [formGroup]="applicationUserForm">
    <mat-form-field style="width: 100%">
        <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Choose Department..." formControlName="department" [matAutocomplete]="autoGroup">
        <mat-autocomplete #autoGroup="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of autoCompleteData | search: applicationUserForm.value.department" [label]="group.casinoName">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let dept of (group.departments)">
          {{ dept.DEPARTMENTNAME }}
                    </mat-option>
            </mat-optgroup>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

> Right now, in my current solution, value is getting filtered but i am getting filtered value with whole values in mat group.

I need only single value to be displayed if filter matches that value.

I have made a stackblitz. Any leads would be appreciated

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-8kj3u1?file=app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter the on the options, not just the groups:

```
<mat-form-field style="width: 100%">
  <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Choose Department..." formControlName="department" [matAutocomplete]="autoGroup">
  <mat-autocomplete #autoGroup="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of autoCompleteData | search: applicationUserForm.value.department" [label]="group.casinoName">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let dept of (group.departments) | searchOptions: applicationUserForm.value.department">
        {{ dept.DEPARTMENTNAME }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-optgroup>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

And obviously create a new pipe to work with the options:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'searchOptions'
})
export class SearchOptionsPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: Array<any>, args?: any): any {
    if (!args) {
      return items;
    }
    return items.filter(
      item => item.DEPARTMENTNAME.toLowerCase().indexOf(args.toLowerCase()) >= 0
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But then this approach show another group header if value is not available in second mar group. Please let me know how i can make sure that complete optgroup filters if option is not available in that group

Comment: Use your original pipe on the groups in addition to my pipe on the options.